# Why does Naruto have a catch phrase?

Tags: naruto

In both the anime and manga Naruto often ends his sentences with either "dattebayo" or "believe it" in the English translations.

Why is this a thing?

Is it meant to further his character or provide a bit of remembrance of his character to the reader or viewer, or even other characters of the series?

Comment: I actually stop hearing him say that in Naruto:Shippuden.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In chapter 498 of the manga, it is mentioned that Naruto inherited this habit from his mother, Kushina, who would instead end her sentences with "(Da)-ttebane" ([だ]ってばね) when she got excited or angry. She also mentioned something along the lines of hoping that her son wouldn't inherit this habit.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: After 489 chapters the mangaka reveals a great mystery, why Naruto ends his sentences a certain way... or he just decided why not make something up... that sounds more likely to me since Naruto started as a one-shot :)

Comment: Than after Naruto had kids, his older son, Boruto, inherited that too.

Comment: Dattebane - Kushina, Dattebayo - Naruto, Dattebasa - Boruto.