# Why does Sakura's inner voice say "cha" at the end of her sentences?

Tags: naruto

So [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/128/1587) explains why Naruto say "dattebayo" or "believe it" in the English translations, being that he inherited it from his mother.

In earlier episodes of Naruto when Sakura goes to think of what she really wants to say, this occurs in the form of white drawing lines of Sakura with writing on her forehead with black background. See the image below:

[image: second Sakura]

In the English dub, the second Sakura often ends her sentences by saying *"cha"*.

What is the reason for this? Is this something she picked up from her parents like how Naruto inherited his mother's habit, or is there some other explanation for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [*Catchphrases and Verbal Tics from Naruto Wikia*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Catchphrases_and_Verbal_Tics#Shannar.C5.8D_and_Shannar.C5.8Dy.C5.8D), the phrase ***"Cha"*** was replacement of ***"Shannarō"*** and ***"Shannarōyo"*** in the English dub often used by *Inner Sakura*, which have no literal meaning, but it can be translated into ***"Hell yeah!"***, ***"Hell no!"***, or ***"Damn it!"*** depending on the situation.